# FileNotFoundException while reading a xlsx file

Tags: java, filereader, filenotfoundexception, fileinputstream

I'm trying to read a .xlsx file from the project folder using the following code, but it always throws `FileNotFoundException`. I have attached the project structure where the file is.

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    try {
        String excelFilePath = "‪DataModel.xlsx";
        File file = new File(excelFilePath);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);         

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.print(ex);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should be using DataModel.xlsx instead of DataModel.txt

Comment: Infact I used xlsx only. Modified it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I normally would approach it:

```
File file = new File( javaApplication2.class.getResource( excelFilePath ).getPath() );
```

Comment: I fixed the problem using classLoader.getResource(). I agree with you voipdaddy, this is a better approach

Comment: Keep in mind, that with `getResource` you only can read Files that are within the classpath. So when your program is in production that Excel-File must be in the classpath (either in the jar or added via the `-cp` parameter of java)!

Answer (score 0):

classLoader.getResource() solved the problem